# Authentication of a login form using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the code below the `alert` is giving me `undefined`. I think the problem is due to the backslash in the URL or with something else.
this is the json structure

```
"{
            \"UserName\":\"abc\",
            \"Password\":\"123456\"
}"
```

How do I validate the username and password the user has entered is present in the URL?

```html
<form action="#" id="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName" class="font-weight-bold" style="width:100%;">Username<a href="#" class="float-right font-weight-light axa-color">Forgot?</a></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="font-weight-bold" style="width:100%;">Password<a href="#" class="float-right font-weight-light axa-color">Forgot?</a></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#login_btn").click(function() {
  var userName = $("#userName").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  authenticate(userName, password);
});

function authenticate(userName, password1) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    url: "http://api/User/login",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {
      username: userName,
      password: password1
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: If you're seeing the `alert()` it means the request is successful, and if you see `undefined` it means there's no data returned from the request. What response are you expecting? It's possible that a 200 or 204 response from the call means the user was authenticated, but it depends entirely on the endpoint you're calling. As such we can't really help given the lack of information about your expectations of the request. Also note that `async: false` is incredibly bad practice and needs to be removed.

Comment: What are you expecting as a response?

Comment: @Atal Shrivastava can you update your backend code and console log the data that you are getting

Comment: @abhinavxeon its just a json. i have updated the question?  I need to look into the json whether username and password available there or not. If yes go to dashboard else throw error

Answer (score 0):

Change data to:

```
data: {
    userName: userName,
    password: password
},
```

(You have written it at the wrong position.) After that, your undefined error will be gone.

In function(), you also wrote `password1` instead of `password`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the object you are passing to the `$.ajax` function, you need a `,` after `"POST"`:

```js
$("#login_btn").click(function() {
  var userName = $("#userName").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  authenticate(userName, password);
});

function authenticate(userName, password1) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {
      username: userName,
      password: password1
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName" class="font-weight-bold" style="width:100%;">Username<a href="#" class="float-right font-weight-light axa-color">Forgot?</a></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="font-weight-bold" style="width:100%;">Password<a href="#" class="float-right font-weight-light axa-color">Forgot?</a></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```